# How to add headers to columns with second column as directory name

Tags: linux, bash, loops, sed, bioinformatics

I have count file containing IDs and counts in multiple directories (for each accession SRRXXXXX). I want to add header "gene_id" and SRRabcdXXX in each file using bash loop.

Directory structure like this:

```
SRRabcd
  count.txt
SRRefgh
  count.txt
```

MY FILE(s)

```
gene1 194
gene2 40
```

WHAT I AM DOING

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in /home/path/to/dir/SRR*/
do
sed -i '1s/^/gene_id\t"${dir}"\n/' "$dir"/count.txt
done
```

MY OUTPUT

```
gene_id "${dir}"
gene1 194
gene2 40
```

My Desired Output (for individual files)

```
gene_id SRRabcdef
gene1 194
gene2 40
```

Comment: You typed single quotes around your string (the second argument to sed) instead of double quotes, so Bash will not perform and variable substitution in the string, and Bash just passes `${dir}` to the sed instead of an actual directory name.

Comment: By passing ${dir}, its returning: gene_id ${dir}

gene1 194

gene2 40

Comment: sed -i '1s/^/gene_id\t"${dir}"\n/' "$dir"/count.txt; sed -i '1s/^/gene_id\t'${dir}'\n/' "$dir"/count.txt; sed -i '1s/^/gene_id\t${dir}\n/' "$dir"/count.txt is giving same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace `${dir}` with its actual value you need to insure `${dir}` is wrapped in double quotes; while you do have `"${dir}"` in your `sed` script, this is embedded in a pair of single quotes which effectively negates the inner double quotes with the net result that you end up the literal string `"${dir}"` in your output.

One easy approach would be to append 3 strings together to form your `sed` script, eg:

```
# '1s/^/gene_id\t' + "${dir}" + '\n/' 

sed '1s/^/gene_id\t'"${dir}"'\n/'
```

But the simpler (and recommended) approach is to insure the entire `sed` script is wrapped in double quotes, eg:

```
sed "1s/^/gene_id\t${dir}\n/" "$dir"/count.txt
    ^                       ^
```

Sample data:

```
$ head SRR*/count.txt
==> SRRabcd/count.txt <==
gene1 194
gene2 40

==> SRRefgh/count.txt <==
gene1 395
gene2 17
```

Modified script:

```
for dir in SRR*
do 
    echo "########## $dir"
    sed "1s/^/gene_id\t${dir}\n/" "$dir"/count.txt
done
```

This generates:

```
########## SRRabcd
gene_id SRRabcd
gene1 194
gene2 40
########## SRRefgh
gene_id SRRefgh
gene1 395
gene2 17
```

Once you confirm the results are correct you can add the `-i` flag.

Comment: THANKS a lot. It worked. Below is the script

Comment: for dir in */
do 
    echo "${dir%*/}" (# remove the trailing "/")
    sed -i "1s/^/gene_id\t${dir%*/}\n/" "$dir"/count.txt
done